# Boost Mp11: Check that every value in a map is a member of a given list

Tags: c++, boost, c++20

I have the following list and map:

```
using List
    = boost::mp11::mp_list<EntityType, Name, Input, Position, Velocity,
                           Rotation, AnimationState, Interaction>;

using Map = boost::mp11::mp_list<
    boost::mp11::mp_list<Input, Input, Position, Velocity, Rotation>,
    boost::mp11::mp_list<AnimationState, AnimationState>>;
```

How can I check that every value in the map is a member of the list? The keys don't need to be members of the list.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/KzeP7qzdq

Comment: @Osyotr Should `mp_second` be `mp_rest`?

Comment: @康桓瑋 I don't think it makes any difference.

Comment: @Osyotr https://godbolt.org/z/xq3xq87ec For the *map* concept in `boost::mp11`, shouldn't *value* be the rest elements except the first element? Or does the *value* only refer to the second element? I'm not sure since I'm not a huge fan of `mp11`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 you're right, the concept of map in mp11 is list of lists, without size restriction. It then becomes slightly more complicated https://godbolt.org/z/nde33nK13